# Why are there rough patches on my models?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, image

Recently the models I've been importing have had patchy shading (I don't really know how to describe it). The patches disappear when I change the roughness to be higher or lower. Any explanation for this? I'm certain its on a roughness level because they disappear when i disconnect the roughness map. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: dark patches on apples]

[image: dark patches on plant]

[image: Node setup]

Also, please note that the Poliigon node group itself isn't causing the issue as the problem persists when plugging in the roughness map (with non-color data) directly (without the node group).

Comment: You may have to post a screenshot of your node set up for people to better help you.

Comment: What could also help is to share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: I'll add a screenshot of the node setup, though it's essentially a roughness map (non-color data) plugged into the roughness input of a Principled BSDF node, which I've used a million times before without any problems.

Comment: What happens when you disconnect your normal input and use base normals?  That's where I suspect the problem lies-- in whatever normal that node group is creating.  But, yeah, file is really the only way to do this that isn't just a game of twenty questions.

Comment: I already tried that. It looks the it would be the normals but it’s not, as the issue persists after disconnecting the normal map. And as for sharing the blend file, I usually would but in this case I don’t believe I’m able to as the models with the problem are paid and I can’t redistribute them. Sorry I can’t provide the files but I left a message on their website so maybe they’ll be able to answer it on there.